ASP.NET Core 8.0 JWT Authentication not working on others controller except the Authentication Controller
I'm encountering an issue with JWT authentication in my ASP.NET Core 8.0 application. While the token generation and authentication seem to work correctly in my AuthenticationController, any requests to other controllers requiring authorization are returning 401 Unauthorized.
Environment:

ASP.NET Core Version: 8.0
Hosting Environment: Azure

Problem description
The JWT token is generated and validated successfully in the AuthenticationController. However, when I try to access other controllers that require authorization, I receive a 401 Unauthorized response. The JWT issuer, audience, and secret are configured correctly in Azure and are being used successfully in the AuthenticationController.
For testing purposes, I added the action that I want to use in the other controller (which doesn't work) inside the AuthenticationController, and it works even without the [Authorize] attribute on that controller.
using Expenses.Data;
using expensesBE.Data.DTO.Interfaces;
using expensesBE.Data.DTO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Carica le variabili d'ambiente
var jwtIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_ISSUER");
var jwtSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_SECRET");
var jwtAudience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_AUDIENCE");

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwtIssuer) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwtSecret) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwtAudience))
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("JWT configuration is missing");
}

// Costruisci la stringa di connessione
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

// Configura Identity
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

// Configura l'autenticazione JWT
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtIssuer,
        ValidAudience = jwtIssuer,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSecret))
    };
});

// Aggiungi i servizi personalizzati
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExpensesServices, ExpensesServices>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

// Configura CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseSwagger(); // Enable Swagger
app.UseSwaggerUI(); // Enable Swagger UI

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace expensesBE.Data.DTO.Utilities
{
    public static class JwtGenerator
    {
        public static string GenerateUserToken(string username)
        {
            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
            };

            return GenerateToken(claims, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1));
        }

        private static string GenerateToken(Claim[] claims, DateTime expires)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var secret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_SECRET");
            var issuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_ISSUER");
            var audience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_AUDIENCE");
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = expires,
                Issuer = issuer,
                Audience = audience,
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using expensesBE.Models;
using expensesBE.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using expensesBE.Data.DTO;
using Expenses.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace expensesBE.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize] // Richiede l'autenticazione per tutte le azioni del controller
    public class ExpensesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public ExpensesController(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // POST: api/expenses
        [HttpPost("AddExpense")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddExpense([FromBody] Expense expense)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState); // Ritorna un BadRequest se il modello non è valido
            }

            var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? User.FindFirst("unique_name")?.Value;
            expense.UserId = userId; // Associa l'ID utente alla spesa

            _context.Expenses.Add(expense);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Created("api/expenses/AddExpense", expense); // Ritorna CreatedAtAction
        }
    }
}


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using expensesBE.Data.DTO.CustomExceptions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using expensesBE.Data.DTO.Interfaces;
using expensesBE.Data.DTO;
using Expenses.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Expenses.Data; // Aggiungi questo spazio dei nomi
using expensesBE.Models;

namespace expensesBE.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

        public AuthenticationController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IUserService userService, AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userService = userService;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpPost("signup")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _userService.Signup(userDto);

                return Created("", result);
            }
            catch (UsernameAlreadyExistsException e)
            {
                return StatusCode(409, e.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("signin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _userService.SignIn(userDto);

                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (InvalidUsernamePasswordException e)
            {
                return StatusCode(401, e.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("ConfirmEmail")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return BadRequest("UserId and Token are required");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound("User not found");
            }

            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok("Email confirmed successfully");
            }

            return BadRequest("Email confirmation failed");
        }

        [HttpPost("AddExpense")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddExpense([FromBody] Expense expense)
        {
            if (expense == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Expense data is required");
            }

            // Verifica se l'UserId esiste nella tabella AspNetUsers
            var userExists = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(expense.UserId) != null;

            if (!userExists)
            {
                return BadRequest("The specified UserId does not exist.");
            }

            // Aggiungi la nuova spesa al contesto del database
            await _dbContext.Expenses.AddAsync(expense);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(AddExpense), new { id = expense.Id }, expense);
        }
    }
}

Accessing protected endpoints: I created an ExpensesController with [Authorize] attribute to protect the endpoints. I used the token to make a request to the protected AddExpense endpoint.
Testing with Postman: I used Postman to send requests to the AddExpense endpoint with the JWT token included in the authorization header as Bearer <token>. Despite this, I received a 401 Unauthorized response.
Checking Token Claims: I verified the token using jwt.io to ensure it contains the correct claims and is correctly signed. The token appears valid according to the website.
Alternative Testing: For testing, I temporarily moved the AddExpense action to the AuthenticationController and confirmed it worked without the [Authorize] attribute, suggesting the issue is with authorization handling rather than the token itself.

Hi @user22096230, it seems you do not understand the Authorize attribute. And your code AddExpense is not related with the any about the authorization. 401 means the token is not correct or missed. Pls share how do you send the token and also pls decode the jwt token if it contains correct payload.
